# Ubuntu 20.04 No Display Port Sound

Tags: sound, 20.04, displayport

Just upgraded from 19.10; audio worked fine before the upgrade.

Sound coming from AMD Radeon 5700XT over display port. Monitor is an AOC U3477PQU.

Ryzen 3700X; Asus Pro WS X570-ACE MB; 32GB RAM.

Comment: Tested the line out and headphones; both work.

Also if I select the Display Port output the sound just gets sent to the headphones or line out.